# jenkins - docker: command not found.. path setup

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-cli

SO i'm very new to jenkins and I'm trying to use jenkins to automatically build my docker image.

- using the freestyle project
- under build step i added an **execute shell**
- added "docker images" (to see if docker worked)
- cont

**following error:**

**command**:

docker images

**output**:

/var/folders/ym/d71xv1gx4fq16slmbtkmwr680000gn/T/jenkins80660521833580 63134.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE

however

if I issue the following command

/usr/local/bin/docker images -- this works

**question**

- How do I setup the path variable for docker so that I don't have to specify the path to the docker binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

enables extras

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras
```

installs docker

```
yum -y install docker-ce
```

starts docker

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

test runs if docker is installed

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

enables docker to start up on boot up

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
```

with these commands the above error didn't occur.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest checking what's the job `PATH` variable is. In your **execute shell** script add `echo $PATH` on the top, run the job again and see in the console output the result of that echo command, if the `/usr/local/bin` is in the PATH. If not, you should probably modify your PATH in the global jenkins configuration - Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> under Global Properties, Environment Variables should be checked, PATH var added and it should contain the `/usr/local/bin` path (together with all the other paths). For testing purposes, you can run `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` on the top section of your shell script to see if the docker command runs.

Comment: Thank you so much!!